# BCD to ASCII conversion

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I know that every 4 bit in BCD is one digit in decimal, but I have a problem, for example when I want to print a BCD value stored in CH I do this :

```
add ch, 30h
```

but, when the value is 12, it prints "C", I want to print "12". 
How can I do operations on 4 bit of data?

Comment: 12 in BCD is 12h, if you add 30h you get 42h which is B, not C. You'll just have to use `AND` and shifts to split it and go from there.

Answer (score -1):

```
mov al,ch      ; if ch has 12h
aam            ; ax will now be 0102h
or ax,3030h    ; converting into ascii - ax will now become 3132h
; you can now print the value in ax
mov cx,ax
mov dl,ch      ; to print on screen
mov ah,02h
int 21h
mov dl,cl
int 21h
ret
```

[8086 AAM Instruction](http://wikidev.in/wiki/assembly/8086/AAM)

[8086 INT 21h function to print a character](http://wikidev.in/wiki/assembly/8086_INT_21H/AH02H)

Comment: The code is wrong! This `AAM` instruction will divide by **10**, but in order to convert from 12h into 0102h you need to divide by **16**.