# printing a BCD value (MASM)

Tags: assembly, masm, x86-16

I wrote a code with interrupt 1ah, and I did this :

```
mov al, ch
and al, 0fh
mov dl, al
```

Now, for example time is "18:36", it shall print hours, and only prints 8. Because I wanted program to do this. But, what can I do to show "1"?

P.S : I tested masking lower nibble, but it wasn't my answer.

Comment: Would you post your full code?

Comment: If you are really operating on BCD values, you should have a look at the instructions `AAA`, `AAD`, `AAM`, `AAS`. They do 'ASCII adjust after ...'.

Comment: As advised for your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37024912/bcd-to-ascii-conversion) you must print each nibble separately. Shift the upper nibble into lower position, mask, add '0', print character. Then mask the lower nibble, add '0', print. Of course, you must work with a *copy* because the first operation trashes the 2nd digit.

Comment: To be redundantly clear, if `al` contains `18` in BCD, then `1` is in the high nibble, and `8` is in the low nibble. Your `and al, 0fh`, etc, get the low nibble (8) but you ignored the high nibble. You obtain that by `shr al, 4`. 0 will be shifted into the upper bits by `shr`. You'd print that value first since it's the first digit.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code you need to print the hours in the `CH` register.

```
mov bl, cl   ;Save-guard the minutes!
mov dl, ch
mov cl, 4    ;On 8086 you need to use CL
shr dl, cl   ;High nibble
add dl, 30h  ;Make character
mov ah, 02h  ;DOS PrintChar
int 21h
mov dl, ch
and dl, 0fh  ;Low nibble
add dl, 30h  ;Make character
mov ah, 02h  ;DOS PrintChar
int 21h
```

Because on 8086 there's no *immediate* shift count you have to use the `CL` register. Therefore it's necessary to move the *minutes* in the `CL` register to another register like `BL`