# How to convert from BCD to ASCII and print the result?

Tags: ubuntu, assembly, bios, bcd

I want to output the RTC date.

I realized that I had to convert from BCD to ASCII in order to do that, but I do not know what to do.

To convert, I use this page: [BCD to ASCII conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37024912/bcd-to-ascii-conversion), but it uses interrupt 21h and in this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS_interrupt_call interrupt 21h does not exist.

How can I convert and print BCD?

```
DAY:
mov ah,0x04
int 0x1a
mov al,dl
aam ;to convert.
mov bx,ax
mov cx,ax
add dl,ch
mov ah,02h
int 21h
mov dl,cl
int 21h
```

I tested the code in ubuntu. I think I should use interrupt 10h for output and not 21h. (`int 21h` is not *active*).

So, how to convert BCD to ASCII, and how to print it using interrupt 10h?
Just use following style?

```
mov al, 'h'
int 10h
```

Comment: PS. I don't use DOS interrupt. It is a violation of the rules given to me.
Just use 'bios interrupt call' in wikipedia page.

Comment: You may find this useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_10H

Comment: Note that you can't use DOS interrupts on Ubuntu. After all, Ubuntu isn't DOS but rather a Linux. Are you running your code in Dosbox or something like that?

Comment: I already described the process for you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46074535/how-to-print-rtc-use-assembly-interrupt-vector-1ah#comment79172489_46083282) the last time you asked. Looking at the code above, I'm not seeing that you have even tried to do this. While I'm willing to *help* people with their homework, I'm not going to do it all for them.  Given that printing integers isn't 'trivial', you are probably going to want to create a PROC that takes an integer parameter, and prints out each of the digits.  Then you can call this PROC for each of the numbers you want to print.

Comment: I tring use PROC but using (A PROC { code } A ENDP), Occur 'A redifined' error.. I don't know why the error occur.

Comment: Can i use jump rether than PROC/call?

Comment: What assembler are you using?  If you are going to call the PROC more than once, jump doesn't work very good.  How do you know where to jump back to when it is done?

Comment: Oh. crap. You means if { A func{ call P}, B func {call P}, ..., P proc {code} P endp}, proc jump is strange working? // I using nasm assembler // Will it work if I put proc code in every caller?, I now seeing this [link](https://github.com/kingspp/8086-MicroProcessor/blob/master/Date-Program.asm)

Comment: And one more question. Assembly is also compiling line by line? I trying insert code in completed code. But maybe it dosen't working. : <, I think just i trying poor call or make poor codes, but just wondering..

Comment: Defining functions is done differently depending on which assembler you are using.  There's a good explanation/example about using `call` with nasm [here](http://asmtutor.com/#lesson4).  As for how to use it, picture something like `mov al, ch; call writeint; mov al, cl; call writeint; mov al, dh; call writeint`.

Comment: I trying another way to solve problem. (Using RTC, to get Date) `mov ah,04h; int 1Ah, mov ax,[dl](http://vitaly_filatov.tripod.com/ng/asm/asm_029.5.html); mov cl,ax; `(I got print code using cl :`mov cl,'a'; mov ch, (color code); mov bx, (postion); mov [bx], cx )`  But mov ax, dl & mov cl, ax line is invalid opcode & operands error. Where is the problem using interrupt 1Ah?

Comment: The print code is here: `org 100h; 
mov ax, 0b800h ;
mov ds, ax;
mov cl, 'A';
mov ch, 11011111b;
mov bx, 15eh;
mov [bx], cx;
ret;`

Comment: Are you trying it in environment, where you have debugger? If not, maybe change environment and try with debugging, it may help you to visualise the process of the computation. `BOCHS` virtual machine is said to have debugger (I didn't try myself, just keep seeing it here in questions about developing bootloaders and kernels). Investing like half of day to set it up and learn how to control + debug it may give you tremendous advantage later. And you have wrong tags on this question. "ubuntu + assembly" is completely off your real target platform.

Comment: I already use Bochs environment. but i can't trying Bochs debugger because if i trying 'make' in console, error message printed in console. so i not trying in Bochs if my code has trouble.

Comment: I downvoted, because an assembly question that doesn't specify the architecture (we can understand from the snippet that it's x86, but you didn't state it anywhere; and most importantly, 16, 32 or 64 bit? What mode?), the assembler used (from the snippet may be MASM, NASM or TASM) and the target environment (you talk about BIOS calls, about Ubuntu, and link code that use DOS int 21h - WTF?) is essentially unanswerable and a big waste of time for everyone involved, as everyone here is "filling the blanks" in a different way.

Comment: @LocketGoma Please note that the answer on the page [BCD to ASCII conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37024912/bcd-to-ascii-conversion) is wrong! The `AAM` instruction is not used in the correct manner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is [BCD (binary-coded decimal)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal)?

In case of the BIOS time interrupt result, the "packed BCD" is used. Each byte (8 bits) is split into two halves of 4 bits (nibbles), each containing one decimal value (4 bits allow for 0-15 values, but only 0-9 values are used to stay "decimal").

So for example if the time is ending with "37" seconds, the seconds byte will contain value `0x37 = 55 = 0b00110111`. Notice how both in hexadecimal and binary the 4-bit halves are visible/readable even by human after short practice (in decimal not, you have to calculate in head the division/remainder by 16 to split it into 3 and 7: `55 / 16 = 3`, `55 % 16 = 7`).

Now assembly is pretty straightforward with bit fiddling, so even if you don't want to delve into the specialized BCD instructions like [`AAM`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/AAM.html), you can use ordinary bit masking + shifting to extract the two values.

Let's say you have value `0x37` in `BL`, and you want to extract it into `BH` (`0x03`) and `BL` (`0x07`), then for example this code will calculate that:

```
mov bh, bl   ; copy the packed value also into BH
and bl, 0x0F ; keep only lower 4 bits in BL (0x37 & 0x0F = 0x07)
shr bh, 4    ; shift right by 4 bits BH (unsigned(0x37) >> 4 = 0x03)
; and that's it, it's that simple to manipulate bits in assembly
```

How to display it?

That depends on your target platform, judging from question and comments you are aiming for x86 16b real mode on PC compatible computer with only BIOS available, so one of the easiest ways is to convert those decimal 0-9 values into ASCII values of digits (adding 48 works, or many assemblers will do conversion from chars for you, so for example `add bl,'0'` works, and you can think about it as "add font character 0 to 0-9 value", and as the next digits in font are defined in +1 way from `'0'`, it will calculate the correct character value).

And then use one of the [`int 10h`](http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_10.html) services to display the ASCII character, like the `AH=0x0A` service. Example of displaying the ASCII character from `BL`:

```
mov ah, 0x0A  ; write ASCII character
mov al, bl    ; character value to write
xor bx, bx    ; bh = bl = 0 in text mode (adjust in gfx mode as needed)
mov cx, 1     ; write it only once
int 0x10      ; call the BIOS service
```

As you want to display the time, and you have the values in several registers, you will probably need to preserve them between printing, for example, if I would use [`int 0x1A,02`](http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_1a-2.html) service to read RTC, I would use this "architecture" to display it (not writing full implementation, just the top logic to show you how you can use `push/pop` stack instructions to preserve values for later usage):

```
read_and_display_rtc_time:
    mov  ah,2
    int  0x1A     ; call service 00 of RTC BIOS interrupt
    push dx       ; preserve DH (seconds)
    push cx       ; preserve CL (minutes)
    mov  al,ch    ; AL = CH (hours)
    call display_bcd   ; display AL as BCD-packed decimal value
    call display_colon ; display ":"
    pop  ax       ; restore minutes (push cx) into AL
    call display_bcd   ; display AL as BCD-packed decimal value
    call display_colon ; display ":"
    pop  ax
    mov  al,ah    ; restore seconds into AL
    call display_bcd   ; display AL as BCD-packed decimal value
    ret

display_bcd:
    ; AL contains BCD-packed decimal value (4:4 bits)
    ; TODO code to split it into two values, convert to ASCII and display
    ret

display_colon:
    ; TODO code to display colon on screen
    ret
```

---

Now I will comment on some of your problems in comments:

```
mov cl,ax
```

Yes, that's not legal, because `ax` is 16 bit register, and `cl` is 8 bit register (alias for lower 8b part of `cx`), so you would lose 8 bits in such operation.

To show as programmer that you indeed do *want* to lose the upper 8 bits, you can write `mov cl,al` (`al` is alias of lower 8 bits of `ax`).

The opposite conversion like `mov ax,cl` will again fail, but again as a programmer you can define precisely, how the 8 bit value should be converted into 16 bits value.

For example to do "unsigned" conversion you can use either the 386+ instruction:

```
movzx ax,cl
```

Or 8086-80286 calculation way:

```
xor ax,ax   ; set all bits of AX to zero first
mov al,cl   ; copy the CL into lower 8 bits of AX
```

And for "signed" conversion there's again specialized 386+ way:

```
movsx ax,cl
; or before 80386 times there are two common options
mov   al,cl     ; if "ax" is target, then there's special instr.
cbw             ; sign extend AL into AX
; or when non-ax register is target, like DX
mov   dh,cl     ; copy CL into upper 8 bits first
sar   dx,8      ; now do sign-right-shift by 8 bits
  ; dx = sign extended CL
```

---

Just keep in mind the computer is a bit more complex calculator, nothing else, so you should try to convert from the word task into thinking which numerical values you have on the input side, what numeric values represent output side (even "characters" are just numeric values in computer), and then you just figure out mathematical formulas to convert the input numbers into output numbers.

If you have bochs, comment out code which does not compile yet, and start with small chunk of code which works, check in debugger what they are doing, so you can visually see how the calculation is going on, then add slowly new parts of code by 2-3 instructions, and keep running them in debugger to see if they calculate what you want. (the overuse of word "calculate" in recent paragraphs is intentional.. if you know how to operate the calculator, you are pretty close to know how to code in assembly, although your initial source will be probably ugly, as it takes time to pick up also "style" and efficiency - just check the instruction set to understand what kind of calculations are possible and get better insight into what means that `AX` is 16 bit register, and `AL` is 8 bit, and how the numeric values are encoded in bits (electricity current)).

---

> "tested in ubuntu"

Not exactly, you ran just `nasm` in ubuntu to produce 16bit x86 machine code binary (cross-compiling, you can produce such binary on any other machine, which has x86 assembler, not really relevant to your questions, except you should specify NASM, so people trying to answer you will know which x86 assembly syntax to use, each assembler has tiny differences). Then you did try that binary in virtual machine (BOCHS). If you would try to run it directly under ubuntu, it would fail completely, as ubuntu OS doesn't support runtime environment for 16b real mode machine code.

When unsure what is relevant, just describe all of your tools, and command lines/options you use.

Comment: Thank you for answer. i will trying it.

Comment: You should probably mention that after unpacking a pair of BCD digits into a 16-bit register, you can convert both halves to integer with `add bx, '00'`.  You could store that to memory and print as a string, or print one at a time.  Or even `lea cx, [bx+'00']`